# What is John Carter's 'Martian name'?

Tags: john-carter

What is the Martian name of John Carter?

The name appears in the movie where Carter is given a Martian name. I think it was something like "Datar Soyat"(?).

Comment: It's 'Dotar Sojat' which means "My right hand man" in Martian. I don't think its a name though. They called him Virginia (Mainly because he introduces himself as John Carter from Virginia).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Dotar Sojat

> *A few moments later I saw her deep in conversation with a warrior
> named Zad; a big, hulking, powerful brute, but one who had never made
> a kill among his own chieftains, and a second name only with the metal
> of some chieftain. It was this custom which entitled me to the names
> of either of the chieftains I had killed; in fact, **some of the
> warriors addressed me as Dotar Sojat, a combination of the surnames of
> the two warrior chieftains whose metal I had taken**, or, in other
> words, whom I had slain in fair fight.*
>
> <sub><sup>[A Princess of Mars](http://freeread.com.au/@rglibrary/ERBurroughs/Barsoom/APrincessOfMars.html)</sup></sub>

The old [Disney website for the film](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0kdU-72Xby4J:cdn.dolimg.com/franchise/johncarter/tablet/characters.html%3Ftarstarkas%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) suggests (wrongly) that his Martian name is a translation of the words "***my right arms***".

> Tars Tarkas is the Jeddak of the Tharks, a warrior tribe of green men.
> When Tars befriends John Carter, he is amazed at the Earth Man’s
> incredible strength and leaping abilities. Tars gives Carter the Thark
> name Dotar Sojat, which translates to, “my right arms.”